# Dart Intl DateFormat.parse -1 year difference, bug?

Tags: flutter, dart, intl

when I execute this line of code:

```
 DateTime dt = DateFormat("EEEE dd.MM.yyyy HH:MM").parse("Monday 01.12.2019 17:00");
 print("dt.tostring: " + dt.toString()); //2018-12-01 17:00:00.000
```

The date is getting parsed from 2019 to 2018.
Tried 2020 and that is getting parsed to 2019.

Looks like a bug to me. Shall I make an Issue?
Wanted to ask here to make sure.

`intl: ^0.16.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTime dt = DateFormat("EEEE dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm").parse("Monday 01.12.2019 17:00");
```

you need to use lower-case 'mm' for minutes

Comment: wow, nice thanks. Lel that is stupid of me, but weird that it caused a difference of exactly 1 year.